# How can use data source from mongo db and connect to pentaho bi server 5.4

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

Hi i m trying to Mongo db to Pentaho bi server but i am not able to connect so please can any one share steps for connection.

Comment: What have you tried, and what error are you getting? Pentaho has some documentation and videos that should be a good starting point: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/MongoDB.